# How to make the block title overlap with the block body in tikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

In tikzposter, titles of blocks that span the whole width of the poster tend to waste a lot of precious space. To scale down the block title width with `titlewidthscale` does not help, because the block title is outside the block body. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    17pt,
    a1paper,
    ]{tikzposter} 

\usetitlestyle[
    width=750mm,
    linewidth=2pt,
    titletoblockverticalspace=0mm
    ]{Filled}
\usebackgroundstyle{Empty}
\useblockstyle[roundedcorners=5,linewidth=2pt]{Default}

\title{Some title} %
\institute{Some institute} 
\author{Author 1 \& Author 2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{block title (consuming a lot of space)}{
Text\\Text
}

\block[titleleft,titlewidthscale=0.04]{\hspace{-20em}block title (still consuming a lot of space)}{
Text\\Text
}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like (and  how it should look like):
[image]
Any idea how one could include the title into the body, so that the space to the right of the title can be used?

**BTW:** `titlewidthscale` seems to break `titleleft`. That's why I'm fiddling around with `\hspace` in the example.